# Согласование с условными именами

Tags: согласование, ономастика, род

Как следует согласовывать род с условными именами?
Например, есть парень. Его прозвище "Белая Маска".

Есть предложение:

> "Белая Маска" посмотрел на него.

Правильно будет "посмотрел"? Или "посмотрела"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Правильно:** "Белая Маска" посмотрел на него (согласование по полу).

Розенталь: [§188. Сказуемое при подлежащем - несклоняемом существительном, сложносокращенном слове, нерасчленимой группе слов](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm#%D0%B7_06)

**При подлежащем – прозвище лица сказуемое принимает форму рода, которая соответствует полу называемого лица**, например: В августе Редька приказал нам собираться на линию (Чехов); Из-за суконной занавески появилась «Великий Могол» с подносом (А.Н. Толстой) (речь идет о горничной Луше).

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

**Белая Маска посмотрел на него**

Прежде всего. Кавычек не надо. Если это кличка или прозвище человека или животного (а иное тут трудно представить), то это обычное им собственное. Кавычки нужны только если это прозвище вводится впервые или используется в неожиданном контексте.

В отношении же согласования, тут да, род лица определяет согласование. Поэтому "посмотрел".

Но это все не так однозначено. Вот вам пример из "Кондуита и Швамбрании" Кассиля.

> Борцы добросовестно пыхтели условленные заранее сорок минут, и потом
>   Стальная Маска старательно уложила себя на лопатки.

Есть версия, что здесь вместо прозвища произошла персонификация. 
Пожалуй это тема для отдельного вопроса.