# Стальная Маска старательно уложилА себя

Tags: согласование

В ответах на вопрос [Согласование с условными именами](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/431061) совершенно верно дается правило определения согласования по грамматическому роду при прозвищах и кличках - по физическому роду носителя прозвища.

Однако вот пример обратного (он не единичный, просто искать лень)

> Борцы добросовестно пыхтели условленные заранее сорок минут, и потом
>   Стальная Маска старательно уложила себя на лопатки.
>
> - Увы!.. Маска Смерти победила в сорок  пять  минут,  правильно...  Под Стальной Маской боролся чемпион мира и города Покровска Ричард
>     Синягин.

Кассиль, "Кондуит и Швамбрания"
http://lib.ru/PROZA/KASSIL/kassil1.txt_Piece40.08

Речь идет о цирковых борцах, очевидно мужчинах. 
Как это объяснить?

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, это можно объяснить тем, что зрители не знают, **кто** выступает (оба выступают инкогнито), им, собственно, всё равно, и пол человека сейчас их не интересует, его здесь **называют** Маской, и для них он именно маска, **её образ** вызывает желание согласовывать по женскому роду.

Это не кличка, это переименование по принципу смежности, в филологии это называется синекдохой. Пример синекдохи из детского стихотворения:

И вокруг такой галдёж –

Ничего не разберёшь.

Мчатся мимо мамы, папы,

Пиджаки, жакеты, шляпы.

(И. Резникова)

Кто бы в шляпе ни был, всё равно будет:" *Эй, шляпа, куда пошла?*" Это согласование по грамматическому роду. Вы ссылаетесь на правило  об условных именах

```
 правило определения согласования по грамматическому роду
  при прозвищах и кличках - по физическому роду носителя прозвища.
```

Но здесь речь идёт о несклоняемых существительных http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm#%D0%B7_06
  §188. Сказуемое при подлежащем – несклоняемом существительном, сложносокращенном слове, нерасчленимой группе слов.

У нас же склоняемое существительное, пишется без кавычек, значит, согласуется  в роде, числе, падеже.

Comment: *зрители не знают физического рода носителя* Людмила, ну это же совершенно исключено контекстом. Ну два мужика в цирке борются... И шпрехшталмейстер (конферансье? распорядитель?)  объявляет победителя. Или вы просто неудачно сформулировали?! Я так думаю, что просто идет персонификация, когда маска становится не прозвищем - а действующим лицом. Вы об этом?

Comment: И если вернуться к Розенталю и русскому языку. Вопрос-то даже не в том, как это объяснить с человеческой точки зрения. А в том, где правила на этот счет - или хотя бы изъятие из  розенталевской формулировке.

Comment: Ну, да, формулировка страдает, речь не о том, что не знают, а о том, что он выступает инкогнито, сейчас для них это маска, а не  известный человек. Только это не персонификация, они же не маску наделяют человеческими свойствами, а человека называют маской, это, скорее, метонимия: Эй, красная шапочка, куда пошла?  Сейчас попробую изменить ответ.